# Nexus 2000 pinning best practice

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus-2000

As many known the Nexus 2000 series is a switch which allows a distributed fabric in DC networks. Pinning Nexus 2000 is quite a breeze. I was looking to seek discussion and a general consensus on what others do.

A simple N2K pin is as such.

```
fex 101
pinning max-links 1
description "FEX0101
```

Do many of you lock down what Nexus 2000 device can be assigned to a pin by providing "verification" of the pinned Nexus 2000.

```
fex 102
pinning max-links 1
description "SVRSW-01-102"
serial FOC240831BZ
type N2248TP
```

Does the additional configuration fall into you best practice configuration or is it a must have in your environment and do you add it as a layer of pseudo-physical security?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is considered best practice. Frankly, there's no reason not to. Given that the 2K is essentially just a line card that can be moved around arbitrarily, this is the only way to ensure that it always shows up in the same "slot" of the parent switch.

Answer (score 8):

You absolutely should use the serial command. I'm less worried about what is pinned where, than what happens if a FEX is connected to the wrong port. We were moving some equipment around and two SFPs were swapped. These FEXen were connected to a pair of Nexus 5000 via vPCs and both FEX lost all their configuration. It was a fairly unpleasant experience, and I recommend against it, myself.